# How to show web page in my app?

Tags: android, webkit

I need to send from server side simple web pages (with images) some how (mht, or zipped web page folders) and show it on UI of my Android application without browser control, can someone advice my how to proceed with that on Android device?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To show a web page in your app, there are two ways to do it: use the default Browser of Android, or use a `WebView`. For the second one, you can do this:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
//you can load an html code 
webView.loadData("yourCode Html to load on the webView " , "text/html" , "utf-8");
// you can load an URL 
webView.loadUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

**layout XML :**

In your layout Xml, define an `WebView` like this:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: @Sven Viking : yes of course , in his layout xml , he should define an webView ;)

Comment: Yeah, not suggesting that you didn't mean that :), just clarifying in case it's helpful to him, since he seems to be new to Android development.

Comment: @Sven Viking : i understand you ;) ; and you have +1 vote from me ^^
i will edit my Answer  to add the layout XML :)

Comment: @Houcine: there is a tipo in the xml: should be height i/o heigth.

Comment: just use autocompletion of your code , i mean the android:layout_height

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebView which is an HTML rendering engine that can be dropped into your application just like any other view. It isnt a full browser though, so you control it from your own application logic.