# May I run a WebView in an XML file?

Tags: android, xml, webview

In my activity I have a table that this table includes several `TextViews`.
I want a `WebView` opens a static HTML file, when user clicks on `TextView`.

One way is assigning an Id to each `TextView` and running `OnClickListener` of that `TextView`.

My question is, may I define this process in XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android:onClick attribute is used to define the onClickListener from within your layout XML.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Answer (score 0):

you can define the code in the link , in you onClick method :) ,  refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121513/how-to-show-web-page-in-my-app/6121713#6121713)